# How to save a two-dimensional array into HDFS in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Something like:

```
val arr : Array[Array[Double]] = new Array(featureSize)
sc.parallelize(arr, 100).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

Then Spark will store data type into HDFS.

Comment: Ehm, code looks okay to me - what's the problem?

Comment: I can't save real data in HDFS successfully, just Array[Double]'s type in HDFS.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual data in your `arr`?

Comment: Sure, something like: [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],...[10,11,12]]

Answer (score 2):

`Array` in Scala exactly corresponds to Java Arrays - in particular, it's a mutable type, and its `toString` method will return a reference to the Array. When you save this RDD as textFile, it's invoking toString method on each element of the RDD and therefore giving you gibberish. If you want to output actual elements of the Array, you first have to stringify the Array, for example by applying `mkString(",")` method to each array. Example from Spark shell:

```
scala> Array(1,2,3).toString
res11: String = [I@31cba915

scala> Array(1,2,3).mkString(",")
res12: String = 1,2,3
```

For double arrays:

```
scala> sc.parallelize(Array( Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9) )).collect.mkString("\n")
res15: String = 
[I@41ff41b0
[I@5d31aba9
[I@67fd140b

scala> sc.parallelize(Array( Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9) ).map(_.mkString(","))).collect.mkString("\n")
res16: String = 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

So, your code should be:

```
sc.parallelize(arr.map(_.mkString(",")), 100).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

or

```
sc.parallelize(arr), 100).map(_.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```